# Monitor and restart web3 connection if disconnected

Tags: web3js

Is there a way to listen for web3 connection to node continuously and restart if it fails. I am expecting some similar to this. It is something very common but i can't find this in documentation. If not what approach you all use to deal with disconnection and error.

Note: I am referring to `web3js v1.0`

```
var web3 = new Web3(provider);
web3
    .on('disconnect', function() {
        web3 = new Web3(provider);
    })
    .on('error', function() {
        web3 = new Web(3provider);
    });
```

Also should i use `web3 = new Web3(provider)` or `web3.setProvider(provider)` to reinit?

Answer (score 2):

> Also should i use web3 = new Web3(provider) or web3.setProvider(provider) to reinit?

At least for web3js 1.3.0:

- `web3.setProvider(provider)` will reinit
- Test if still connected by `web3.currentProvider.connected`

So, here's a working solution:

```
const newProvider = () => new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8546', {
        reconnect: {
          auto: true,
          delay: 5000, // ms
          maxAttempts: 5,
          onTimeout: false,
        },
      })
   
const web3 = new Web3(newProvider())

const checkActive = () => {
  if (!web3.currentProvider.connected) {
    web3.setProvider(newProvider())
  }
}

setInterval(checkActive, 2000)
window.addEventListener('focus', checkActive)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such event in the web3 library, but there is another method that does something similar. `isListening` [ref](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-net.html?highlight=islistening#islistening)

You can create a function that will keep polling web3 using `isListening` to check if is still connected or no (`setInterval` might help to achieve it) and reconnect it in case is down.

`web3.setProvider` is used in case you want change the current provided with another one, not sure you will have the right behaviour in case you're going to set the same provided. You need to try out. Creating a new instance with `web3 = new Web3(provider)` could be safer.

Comment: isListening apparently is for http on infura, not websockets, which you now will need for subscribing to events in web3 1.0. https://community.infura.io/t/infura-stop-about-1-hour/104/23

Comment: the OP never mentioned that it was for websockets or HTTP

Comment: It's virtually implied they are using a WebSocket connection if they need to worry about connection persistence in 1.0. All of the http methods requiring such are deprecated in favor of connecting via WebSocket. The only solution I have found is to setInterval a restart of the process. Everything is broken and with workarounds. 2.0 will solve this, allegedly. Your answer doesn't work, hence the downvote. Not personal. I appreciate you thinking of solutions.

Comment: yes you're right actually

Answer (score 0):

> Also should i use web3 = new Web3(provider) or web3.setProvider(provider) to reinit?

In general case when you have to connect to Ethereum network, it is recommended that you use the `getDefaultProvider()` method because it will connect to both Etherscan and INFURA simultaneously.
For example.... If your use case is to connect *to an existing Web3 Provider*

```
// When using a Web3 provider, the network will be automatically detected

// e.g. HTTP provider
let currentProvider = new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');

let web3Provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(currentProvider);
```

> Is there a way to listen for web3 connection to node continuously and
>   restart if it fails.

### I don't know if there are guideline in Ehthereum for this, but I think you should implement some logic to manage this scenario, keeping in mind this:

WebSockets provide a persistent connection between a client and server that both parties can use to start sending data at any time. The **client establishes a WebSocket connection** through a process known as the WebSocket handshake. This process starts with the client sending a regular HTTP request to the server.

*You are* sure the ***client***, so you will have way to play/intercept with Events in order to manage [Connection Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications#Connection_errors).
Take a look at [CloseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent) in the docs of WebSocket and search or try to write something with Web3.

> A CloseEvent is sent to clients using WebSockets when the connection is closed. This is delivered to the listener indicated by the WebSocket object's onclose attribute.